# View Encrypted Fields in integration tools metadata

Tags: integration

I am using an integration tool which integrates data from salesforce to local database . When I select an object I do not see encrypted fields . How does one deal with encrypted fields using integration tools?

Answer (score 2):

> If you have a user with “View Encrypted Data” permission then the user can see encrypted fields in plain text.

Make sure your Integration User profile has this checkbox checked

[image]

Comment: Exactly. This also assumes that you have field-level, record-level, and object-level security to see the field. Can that user see the encrypted field when logged-in via the API?

Comment: @DavidSchach I have not tested from API but i am sure it should provided all permissions are met